# Inject module in another module and use controller of injected module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, module

I want to create a module and inject in main module, and inject the controller into injected module, but it's not working

In index.html

```
<html ng-app="MenuApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl as demo">
<h3>{{demo.hello}</h3>
</body>
</div>
</html
```

In app.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('MenuApp', ['data']);
angular.module('data', [])
.controller('demoCtrl', demoCtrl);
demoCtrl.$inject = [];
function demoCtrl() {
var demo = this;
demo.hello = "Hello World";
console.log('Hello World');
}
})();
```

It's working fine, when I'm declaring the controller(**demoCtrl**) with **MenuApp** Module, but not working when declaring with **data** module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mention the example you gave, your html tags are incorrect, if not codes looks normal. If yo give an error, please share us.

[Codepen example of your codes](https://codepen.io/muratersin/pen/QBydoL)

Following example work well.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('navbar', ['data']);

    angular.module('data', [])
        .controller('DataCtrl', function() {
            console.log('Hello Data');
            this.data = 'Hello Data';
        });
})();
```

And Html is here:

```
<div ng-app="navbar"> 
    <div ng-controller="DataCtrl as ctrl">  
        {{ ctrl.data }}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/muratersin/pen/xJZgzq)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually my html was bit large, so I've reduced and written here, but now it's working.

Thanks once again